# My Random array is giving me the same answer when it should be different

Tags: java, arrays, random

I got my code to work in the expected way, but when i try to make more than one list of permutations it gives me the first one and doesn't change it around.
I need to make a list of permutations from 1 to 10 using an Arraylist and to catch one error that can occur in the code. Then we have to duplicate that code so that we get 9 DIFFERENT lines of permutations.

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
public class Permutations
{

    ArrayList <Integer> Perm = new ArrayList <Integer> ();
    ArrayList <Integer> Print = new ArrayList <Integer> ();
    int counter = 9;
    int List = 1;
    public void ArrayList()
    {
        Perm.add(1);
        Perm.add(2);
        Perm.add(3);
        Perm.add(4);
        Perm.add(5);
        Perm.add(6);
        Perm.add(7);
        Perm.add(8);
        Perm.add(9);
        Perm.add(10);
    }

    public void PermutationGenerator()
    {
        ArrayList();
        Random rand = new Random();
        int value = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
        while(Print.size() < 10)
        {
            try
            {
                while(Print.contains(value))
                {
                    value = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
                }
                Print.add(value);
                Perm.remove(value);
            }
            catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException a)
            {
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("List" + List + ":" + Print.toString());
        List++;
        if(List < 10)
        {
            PermutationGenerator();
        }
    }
```

This is what is printed out:

```
List1:[9,6,5,4,10,2,8,7,1,3]    
List2:[9,6,5,4,10,2,8,7,1,3]    
List3:[9,6,5,4,10,2,8,7,1,3]    
List4:[9,6,5,4,10,2,8,7,1,3]    
List5:[9,6,5,4,10,2,8,7,1,3]    
List6:[9,6,5,4,10,2,8,7,1,3]    
List7:[9,6,5,4,10,2,8,7,1,3]    
List8:[9,6,5,4,10,2,8,7,1,3]     
List9:[9,6,5,4,10,2,8,7,1,3]
```

Comment: i think once your Print size is 10 it is not executing the while loop anymore and printing out the same one over and over

Comment: so do i need to reset all the values to the original values for it to work

Comment: Why do you think it should print different values? Can you describe us which part is responsible for it?

Comment: the code runs once and gets the first line, then i have it in a while loop at the bottom that keeps on running the Generator again so another different  line because of the random function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the PermutationGenerator, you calle the same method recursively. In that point, the variable Print have already 10 random elements inside.

Each time the PermutationGenerator method is executed, you need to empty the Print variable, so the while loop is executed. In your case, the Print variable have always the same 10 elements, so the while loop is executed only the first time, and the Print variable is never modified.

Comment: so if i do removeAll(list)
    if(List < 10)
            {
                 PermutationGenerator();
            }

Comment: Another tip: it's better to try an iterative solution and avoid recursion.

Comment: It seems to work now, thank you, i didn't realize that the loop was not being activated after the first time

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Permutations {

    ArrayList<Integer> Perm = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> Print = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int counter = 9;
    int List = 1;

    public void ArrayList() {
        Perm.add(1);
        Perm.add(2);
        Perm.add(3);
        Perm.add(4);
        Perm.add(5);
        Perm.add(6);
        Perm.add(7);
        Perm.add(8);
        Perm.add(9);
        Perm.add(10);
    }

    public void PermutationGenerator() {
        ArrayList();
        Random rand = new Random();
        int value = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
        //list: 1-9
        while (Print.size() < 10) {
            try {
                while (Print.contains(value)) {
                    value = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
                }
                Print.add(value);
                Perm.remove(value);
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException a) {
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("List" + List + ":" + Print.toString());
        List++;
        if (List < 10) {
            Print.removeAll(Print);
            PermutationGenerator();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Permutations permutations = new Permutations();
        permutations.PermutationGenerator();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I got the answer to show up if i add this line to the final while loop.

```
if(List < 10)
    {
        Print.removeAll(Print);
        PermutationGenerator();
    }
```